# ORA-12154 error TNS could not resolve the connect identified specified

Tags: oracle

while running a java application,I am getting ORA- 12154 error.
In the java application we have to Login using our Database credentials. For some user credentials the application is running successfuly but for others it's throwing error ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifer specified.

Can someone please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The most usual cause for that is that database alias (you're connecting to) isn't included into the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file.

If you have several Oracle software products, there's a good chance that each of them has its own `TNSNAMES.ORA` file (usually located in its `\network\admin` directory). The way of it is to simultaneously edit all those files (which is *stupid*), or create a `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable which will point to a directory that contains your "master" `TNSNAMES.ORA` file, such as I have:

```
M:\>set tns_admin
TNS_ADMIN=C:\0_Oracle_library
```

Therefore, every time I have to add a new database, I edit that `TNSNAMES.ORA` file and all my Oracle programs (Forms, Reports, SQL Developer, TOAD, SQL*Plus, ...) access it and use it.

Comment: or, maybe, create one TNSNAMES.ORA file and create simlink of it into required network/admin directories (if linux used)?

Comment: Maybe, @Gryu. I don't use Linux so I don't know anything about "simlink". TNS_ADMIN option works *everywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle error code documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/ORA-12150.htm#GUID-FF3C136B-78D5-4573-BD45-7D9CAC2A1C0F__GUID-2F73ED66-FB4D-4AB7-82B6-96A54F7A1394) has some helpful troubleshooting tips (the following is from 12.1):

> **ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**
>   **Cause:** A connection to a database or other service was requested using a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming methods configured. For example, if the type of connect identifier used was a net service name then the net service name could not be found in a naming method repository, or the repository could not be located or reached.
>
> **Action:**
>   If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):
>   - Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)
>   - Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.
>   - Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
>   - Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors in a TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.
>
> If you are using directory naming:
>   - Verify that "LDAP" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
>   - Verify that the LDAP directory server is up and that it is accessible.
>   - Verify that the net service name or database name used as the connect identifier is configured in the directory.
>   - Verify that the default context being used is correct by specifying a fully qualified net service name or a full LDAP DN as the connect identifier.
>
> If you are using easy connect naming:
>   - Verify that "EZCONNECT" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
>   - Make sure the host, port and service name specified are correct.
>   - Try enclosing the connect identifier in quote marks. See the Oracle Net Services Administrators Guide or the Oracle operating system specific guide for more information on naming.

Start by checking whether you can `tnsping` the specified service (`tnsping` is a utility included in the Oracle Client). For example, if connecting as `x/y@zzz` fails with ORA-12154, then

```
tnsping zzz
```

This will probably give

```
TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

but it will also display the path of the local `sqlnet.ora` parameter file mentioned above. Depending on your setup there should be other `.ora` files in the same location.

There are a number of ways this can be configured depending on your OS, Oracle client and name resolution setup. (Note that a `tnsnames.ora` file is not the only naming method.) If you share some more details it should be straightforward to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system level environmental variables, i am guessing they override what is in the .NET config file.  In my case there was a SET ORACLE_HOME to an old path.  I removed that (DOS prompt - SET ORACLEHOME=) and it worked.